# Recursively filter nested json data using javascript or rxjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filtering

I am looking to find elegant solution to filter nested json data structure so that filter functionality can be applied.

**pre-condtions:**

- Depth is unknown (needs to be recursive Solution)
- if value doesn't matched and have childrens than all children should be attached to parent 
  and it should be recursive.
- Filter should work more than one By What i mean is if select filter By `Y` and by `Z` than 
  results of Y and Z should be shown in Tree Structure. But currently displayed example below 
  for filter by `kind` property and value to filter applied is `Y` .

Thanks!!

e.g

```
   var dataToFilter = {
        "children": [{
            "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1",
            "children": [{
                "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1-1",
                "children": [{
                        "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1-2",
                        "kind": "Y",
                        "children": [{
                                "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1-3.1",
                                "kind": "X",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1.3.2",
                                "kind": "X",
                                "children": [{
                                    "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1.3",
                                    "kind": "Y",
                                    "children": []
                                }]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "Y",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ],
                "kind": "X",
            }],
            "kind": "Y",
        }]
```

Desired Output on `kind` property when value is e.g `Y` :

````
var desiredOutput = {
        "children": [{
            "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1",
            "children": [{
                    "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1-2",
                    "kind": "Y",
                    "children": [{
                        "tagPath": "/../../tagPath-1.3",
                        "kind": "Y",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Y",
                    "children": []
                }
            ],
            "kind": "Y",
        }]
    ```
````

Comment: In case there is no magic trick, you may find useful some kind of iterator encapsulating recursion for example simple node https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Node_Iterator_IIFE.js or more complex https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
const restructure = (nodes, filter) => nodes.reduce(
    (acc, node) => {
        const children = restructure(node.children, filter);

        return acc.concat(
            filter(node)
                ? {...node, children}
                : children
        );
    },
    []
);
```

Which accepts `filter` as a function. This allows you to decide how to filter, e.g.:

```
const yOnly = restructure(dataToFilter, node => 'Y' === node.kind);
```

Or:

```
const yAndX = restructure(dataToFilter, node => ['Y', 'X'].includes(node.kind));
```

The only difference to your code above is that `dataToFilter` must already be an array of nodes (see the full code snippet below).

```js
const restructure = (nodes, filter) => nodes.reduce(
    (acc, node) => {
        const children = restructure(node.children, filter);

        return acc.concat(
            filter(node)
                ? {...node, children}
                : children
        );
    },
    []
);

const dataToFilter = [{
    'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1',
    'children': [{
        'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1-1',
        'children': [{
            'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1-2',
            'kind':     'Y',
            'children': [{
                'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1-3.1',
                'kind':     'X',
                'children': []
            }, {
                'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1.3.2',
                'kind':     'X',
                'children': [{
                    'tagPath':  '/../../tagPath-1.3',
                    'kind':     'Y',
                    'children': []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            'kind':     'Y',
            'children': []
        }],
        'kind':     'X',
    }],
    'kind':     'Y',
}];

const yOnly = restructure(dataToFilter, node => 'Y' === node.kind);
const xOnly = restructure(dataToFilter, node => 'X' === node.kind);
const yAndX = restructure(dataToFilter, node => ['Y', 'X'].includes(node.kind));

console.log(yOnly);
console.log(xOnly);
console.log(yAndX);
```